# Design Pattern: Similar Fragments with different data sources

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

so I have a design pattern related question. In my Android app I have two very similar Fragments (they use the same layout file) that populate the layout with given data. The only difference is the data source. One Fragment reads the data from a remote database the other one from a local database.

I could think of three options to implement this

1. Retrieve the required data before creating the fragments and then passing the data objects via the fragment's constructor.
2. Create an interface DataRetriever with method retrieve() and to implementations RemoteDataRetriever, LocalDataRetriever and pass this to the fragment.
3. Create to seperate implementations of the fragment or a base class that inflates the layout and two child classes that retrieve the data from different location.

What would you recommend? Or is there another approach I overlooked?

Thanks in advance.
Kind regards.

Comment: I'd go with number 2 above.... and have only one fragment.

Comment: You can go with the second method. But instead of passing a DataRetriever in to your Fragment, create a SimpleRetrieverFactory class and pass an instance of it to the Fragment. Create your Retriever object in the factory and return it to your Fragment.

Comment: @brifbraff thank you both for your response. I'll go with the factory. Cheers.